# Sharepoint - Custom ItemStyle in a new file

Tags: 2007, content-query-web-part

how can I customize the presentation of a Content Query Web Part by modyfing the xsl it uses without touching ItemStyle.xsl but using a brand new .xsl file?

I'm using MOSS 2007.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Export the content query web part (should download as a .webpart file), open it in your favourite text editor, and set the URL to your custom xsl in the XslLink field.

When you're done, rename it and either upload it to the web part gallery then import into a web part page, or directly import it into a web part page.